# Laravel Uploaded File Not Showing in DigitalOcean Spaces

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, digital-ocean

Attempting to use DigitalOcean's Spaces instead of AWS (their UI can go burn in hell)

When I upload a video (364 kb to test) using DropzoneJS it *says* that it uploaded successfully, but for some reason it is not in my DigitalOcean storage, which makes no sense, it would throw an error if it failed right?

Here's the code

HTML

```
<form action="/post/uploadReel" class="dropzone" id="reelUpload">
      {{csrf_field()}}
    </form>
    <script>
      Dropzone.options.photoUpload = {
          maxFilesize:200,
          acceptedFiles: ".mp4,.avi,.flv,.mov",
          paramName: "video",
          parallelUploads: 1,
          maxFiles:5,
          dictInvalidFileType: 'This file type is not supported',
          dictFileTooBig:'File size too big',
          addRemoveLinks: true,
          init: function() {
            this.on('success', function(file, serverFileName) {
                file.serverFileName = serverFileName;
            }),
            this.on('removedfile', function(file) {
              sendData('/post/deleteReel',
              {'name':file.serverFileName},
              function(msg) {
                toastr.success('Deleted Reel');
              },
              function(msg) {
                toastr.error('Server error deleting reel');
              });
            });
          }
      };
    </script>
```

PHP

```
$User = Auth::user();
      $Uploads = Request::get('video');
      $Files = $User->GetUserVideos();
      if(!$User->subscribed() && count($Files) > 0) {
        return "Max Uploads Reached";
      } elseif($User->subscribed() || count($Files) === 0) {
        $name = $Uploads->hashName();
        Storage::disk('spaces')->putFile($name, $Uploads);
        $Reel = Reels::create();
        $Reel->name = $name;
        $Reel->user_id = $User->id;
        $Reel->save();
      }
      return "Uploaded Reel";
```

Also, as an aside, can someone with the reputation to do so create a tag for digital-ocean-spaces? I think it would benefit the community

Thanks

- Zach

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

The issue was that Dropzone was sending the file with name="file" when it was, in theory, supposed to be name="video"